# How to trigger an event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a page that opens a modal window when the user clicks a certain radio button. I want to trigger whatever that event handler is via my own jQuery code. Right now, I'm attempting to mimic a user clicking on the radio button by:

```
$("#myRadioButton").trigger("click");
```

The code works somewhat. The state of the radio button does become selected. However, the modal window does not open.

What must I do to trigger the events and event handlers that make the modal window open?

(Also, is there a way in Chrome DevTools to see what events are attached to an element?)

Comment: What are you using for the modal? Some utility frameworks like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modalshow) have their own custom events and methods for programmatically triggering.

Comment: I want to be oblivious to how the other event handlers are implemented. I just want to trigger whatever happens when a user clicks on the radio button.

Comment: It really depends on how the modal is implemented

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery $el.trigger('change') doesn't fire native listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290775/jquery-el-triggerchange-doesnt-fire-native-listeners)

Answer (score -1):

This will make the click function work, with a id on the element. You will need to make some logic for the modal itself, inside the function.

Not sure there is a way to see the events in the developer console.

```js
 $( "#myRadioButton" ).click(function() {
    
    //Whatever you wants to happen, when you click the button
     alert( "You clicked on #myRadioButton" );
    });
```

Try and check out -> https://jquerymodal.com/

Comment: I do not want to code any logic to open the modal dialog. I want whatever happens when a user clicks on the radio button to also happen when I programmatically "click" the radio button.

Comment: Sorry im not sure i know what you mean. Could you try explaining it in another way?

Comment: What must I do to trigger the events and event handlers that make the modal window open?

Comment: Well i dont know how you made the Modal, so i really cant know.