# Trigger click on a span

Tags: javascript

I want to click on a **SPAN.show-more** automatically. When i click on it shows hidden text. Its ID is a random number something like: SPAN#yui_3_9_1_10_1397969703476_624.show-more
I use greaseMonkey. 
The page is:
https://espanol.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091125151524AAvxaLo

My wrong code is:

```
 var i,
 list = document.querySelectorAll(".show-more")
 for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) 
 { list[i].click();
 }
```

Maybe I need to wait until the page is full loaded? Do I need a delay?

Comment: If you use jQuery, this is really easy to do with `$(yourSelector).click()` or `$(yourSelector).trigger("click')`.

Comment: greaseMonkey can't help do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simulate a click with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call a `onclick()` event like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Click</title>
</head>
<body>

<span class="show-none">hello</span>
<span onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#f47121'" class="show-more">hello</span>
<span onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#128239'" class="show-more">hello</span>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var i, list = document.getElementsByClassName("show-more");
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
   {
     list[i].onclick();
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try this? with `onclick()` method

```
var i, list = document.querySelectorAll(".show-more")
for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) 
{
  list[i].onclick();
}
```

Best regards

Comment: I think what we need is to wait until page loads, because if we manually click on the .show-more before the page loads, nothing happens.

Comment: well, you should use this: document.onload = function(){/*code here*/}

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in, cross-browser function or method to cause a click. One of the best cross-browser solutions I use if ever needed can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript). Althrough, if you're trying to cause a function to fire it would be best to just call the function.

As per Luxelin's suggestion, jQuery would be the easiest alternative. When using jQuery `$(element).trigger('click')` would fire a cross-browser click event on the element.

Answer (score 0):

Though there is a way which you can use:

```
 element.onclick = function(){ .. };

 if( something )
      element.onclick(); // call the handler
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/7vLn7/)**

Comment: @Sam-Bo The base code is here http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/7vLn7/1/ . Now you can implement the necessary actions.

Comment: I have observed that I can't click on the .show-more but until the page load completely, so the code in [link](jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/7vLn7/1) does not work, maybe adding a delay.