# Clicking a button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button

As far as I can tell from my very limited knowledge about JavaScript, it can get all kinds of info about some elements on the page, for example, about a button. JavaScript can get the name of a button, its type, name, and the text in it. It can even disable a button. But can it simulate a click on a button? Or it can and must only be done by a user?

**EDIT 1** (my response to the answer below written by **Narxx**):

This way doesn't seem to work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('my-button').click();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="my-button" onclick="this.innerHTML=Date()">The time is?</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2** (my response to the comment below written by **prash**)

This way doesn't work either (the *simulate* function is written by **[kangas](https://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/master/event.simulate.js)**, modified by **TweeZz**, and is taken by me from **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript)**):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function simulate(element, eventName)
{
    var options = extend(defaultOptions, arguments[2] || {});
    var oEvent, eventType = null;

    for (var name in eventMatchers)
    {
        if (eventMatchers[name].test(eventName)) { eventType = name; break; }
    }

    if (!eventType)
        throw new SyntaxError('Only HTMLEvents and MouseEvents interfaces are supported');

    if (document.createEvent)
    {
        oEvent = document.createEvent(eventType);
        if (eventType == 'HTMLEvents')
        {
            oEvent.initEvent(eventName, options.bubbles, options.cancelable);
        }
        else
        {
            oEvent.initMouseEvent(eventName, options.bubbles, options.cancelable, document.defaultView,
            options.button, options.pointerX, options.pointerY, options.pointerX, options.pointerY,
            options.ctrlKey, options.altKey, options.shiftKey, options.metaKey, options.button, element);
        }
        element.dispatchEvent(oEvent);
    }
    else
    {
        options.clientX = options.pointerX;
        options.clientY = options.pointerY;
        var evt = document.createEventObject();
        oEvent = extend(evt, options);
        element.fireEvent('on' + eventName, oEvent);
    }
    return element;
}

function extend(destination, source) {
    for (var property in source)
      destination[property] = source[property];
    return destination;
}

var eventMatchers = {
    'HTMLEvents': /^(?:load|unload|abort|error|select|change|submit|reset|focus|blur|resize|scroll)$/,
    'MouseEvents': /^(?:click|dblclick|mouse(?:down|up|over|move|out))$/
}
var defaultOptions = {
    pointerX: 0,
    pointerY: 0,
    button: 0,
    ctrlKey: false,
    altKey: false,
    shiftKey: false,
    metaKey: false,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
}
simulate(document.getElementById("btn"), "click");
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn" onclick="this.innerHTML=Date()">The time is?</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 3:** (my response to the answer below written by **Jonco98**):

(**This code is also the answer to my question**)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ClickButton()
{
document.getElementById('my-button').click();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="ClickButton()">
<button id="my-button" onclick="this.innerHTML=Date()">The time is?</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 4:**

Please note that the answer below given by **naomik** also solves my problem perfectly well.

Comment: Events can be triggered from JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript

Comment: For your question, there is already answer here - how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-using-javascript

Comment: @prash - Thank you. I am looking at it at the moment.

Comment: @prash - Sadly, doesn't seem to work either. Please, refer to **EDIT2** section in my question.

Comment: @brilliant, I strongly suggest you see my comments on Jonco's post. You're in for a rude awakening if you continue down this path. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: @naomik - I've looked through them. The more I learn about programming, the more I get to know how much the readability of a code defines its workability. Thank you.

Comment: @brilliant, I posted more on the point I made on painting the button before or after script execution. Hope that helps

Comment: @prash - "Hope that helps" - It does! Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear, happy learning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend doing this [unobtrusively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

```
<button id="my-button">The Time is?</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var b = document.getElementById("my-button");

  function displayTime(elem) {
    elem.innerHTML = Date();
  }

  b.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    displayTime(this);
  });

  // fake the click
  b.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
</script>
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/naomi/3Y9Lm/)

The button loads and is "clicked" with the simulated event immediately. Subsequent clicks will result in the button time being updated.

---

Here's another example:

The time will stop updating after you click submit

```
<form id="my-form">
  <input name="time" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var f = document.getElementById("my-form");

  function updateTime() {
    f.time.value = Date();
  }

  var interval = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);

  f.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    clearInterval(interval);  
    alert("the submitted time is: " + f.time.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  // prepopulate form
  updateTime();
</script>
```

---

References

- [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)
- [EventTarget.dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent)
- [EventTarget.removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener)

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer and for the references.

Comment: @brilliant, the answer you have selected is a very antiquated way of doing javascript; it doesn't keep the javascript separate from the HTML. I added a section to my fiddle that shows an automatically updating timer that stops when a button is pushed. I hope that helps.

Comment: "a very antiquated way of doing javascript; it doesn't keep the javascript separate from the HTML" - Ah, I see. I just tried your code completely out of the HTML "field" (that is, the opening <script type="text/javascript"> tag in it is placed under the closing </html> tag). I never though it would work this way, but it does! Thank you. I am choosing now yours as the best answer.

Comment: @brilliant, correct. You can have scripts anywhere in your HTML, but that's another topic entirely. A pretty safe way is to load most of them just before the closing `</body>` tag. This ensures the DOM elements are loaded before the scripts attempt to reference them. Other methods include loading them in the `<head>` but using some sort of `DOMContentLoaded` listener to make sure they don't run before the rest of the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simulate a click on a button using JavaScript:
HTML:

```
<button id="my-button">Click me</button>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('my-button').click();
```

That's it... you have just triggered a click event on a button without actually clicking it :)

Comment: Thank you! It works. Now, how can I simulate it in such a way so that I get the same result as when you click on the button with your computer mouse?

Comment: What do you mean? This works as if you have clicked it with a mouse. It fires the same event (if I'm not mistaken). What is it *EXACTLY* you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry. I thought you were just pulling my leg. However, when I try your way - that is, when I run an HTML file on my computer with the code suggested by you (please, refer to the EDIT1 section in my question to see it) - it doesn't work. The button's inner text doesn't change into a date info.

Comment: Because you load the script BEFORE the DOM element is loaded. In my code, I first create the DOM element, and then call the JS. Either use a `script` tag after the `<button>` element, or, initialize all event listeners on DOM ready `window.onload` or using jQuery `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Yes, **naomik** and **prash** already explained that to me last night. Thank you for your time, and I am really sorry for my rude response yesterday to your answer.

Comment: You are very welcome, and don't worry about the response. I'm glad it works for you. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not meant as the alternate answer. The answer is already there as suggested by @naomik, and I agree with that.

Let me point out the issue what the OP faced and is unclear why his actual code didn't work though.

Actual code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         document.getElementById('my-button').click();
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button id="my-button" onclick="this.innerHTML=Date()">The time is?</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Simple reason why this didn't trigger the event is because , The `<button>` was not painted at that time, and you would have got this error in your console `Cannot read property 'click' of null`

In the first example that @naomik has shared, this seems to work though. Reason being the place where the `<script>` is executed. It is not in the `<head>`, Its inside the `<body>`, and the `<button>` is painted first before the script execution.

This is good,

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <button id="my-button" onclick="this.innerHTML=Date()">The time is?</button>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         document.getElementById('my-button').click();
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Apart from this, it is advisable to do this via `dispatchEvent()` and `addEventListener()` to simulate and listen to the event.