# Document.getElementById('Button').click(); not triggering Code-Behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I'm new to coding javascript/VB.NET and I'm having trouble making my Button2 onClick event fire.

Code-Behind Click Event for Button1 in Page.aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub _lnbComments_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
           //Some Code that needs to run before opening Modal Page
           Dim Script As String = "JavaScriptCode();"
           ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.upnToolBar, Me.upnToolBar.GetType(), "CommentsClick", Script, True)
End Sub
```

JS File

```
function ShowModal(page,name,style){
    var r = window.showModalDialog(page,window,style);
}
function JavaScriptCode(){
    var jsButton = document.getElementById('ct100_SiteContent__hiddenBtnComments'); //I made sure ClientID is correct
    jsButton.click() //This should trigger onClick event and OPEN modalPage
}
```

Page OnLoad of Page.aspx

```
Me._hiddenBtnComments.Attributes.Add("onclick","ShowModal('SomePage.aspx','SomePage','somestyle')")
```

The Problem is only the Javascript code is being fired and Modal Page is opened. However, after closing Modal Page, the code-behind click Event is NOT triggered. Any Ideas what's wrong with the code?

Page.aspx Button 2 Mark-up

```
<asp:Button id="_hiddenBtnComments" runat="server" style="display:none" onclick="_hiddenBtnComments_click"></asp:Button>
```

Code-Behind Click Event for Button2 in Page.aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub _hiddenBtnComments_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _hiddenBtnComments.Click
//Some Code that needs to run AFTER Modal Page closes.
End Sub
```

EDIT: A friend of mine suggested using window.open instead of window.showmodaldialog() and the code-behind click event is being triggered! However, I need to use window.showmodaldialog since it will be what the users will be expecting,

Comment: Can you show the markup for your button?  Are you wiring up the click event (not JS)?

Comment: I added it, and i declared it at the onclick of the button control.

Answer (score 1):

`click()` doesn't fire click event in JavaScript. Use jQuery or use `dispatchEvent` See this post: [How to simulate a click with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript)

Comment: I tried using the dispatchEvent and it also ONLY triggers the javascript code, which is in this case, the code to open modal dialog/window.

Answer (score 0):

Why not call the ShowModal function in stead of triggering an event?

If you need to have the parameters dynamically you can add data-attributes to your element.

Comment: Yes, that would allow the the Modal Page to open, but I also need the code-behind function _hiddenBtnComments_click() to execute AFTER the modal page closes.