# How to run link on webpage automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a page (**page 1**) that has one link. (**Link A**)
This link when clicked opens a Picture gallery on the same page.

I have another page (**page 2**) that has another link (**Link B**)
This link opens page 1.

**What I want to do is:** 
I want **link A** to be clicked automatically. Immediately **page 1** is opened.

So basically, what happens is once *you click Link B* a Picture Gallery opens.

Is there any HTML code that makes a link run immediately (automatically) the page is opened?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide your code or make a jsFiddle with your code.

Comment: you should be able to trigger a click event  on the link on page load using Javascript / JQuery.  but we'll need to see some code in order to provide a specific answer.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".foo").trigger('click');
});`

Comment: to trigger a link-click on page load: `$(document).ready(function() {  $("a").trigger('click');  });`  where A is yor link. The rest of the question in unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window.location` methods [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) or [href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

```
// js redirect
window.location.replace("http://somesite/somepage");

//same clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://somesite/somepage";
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand, you need to force the click on the link to open the gallery when the **page1** is loaded with JavaScript (you can replace the first parameter of the function and get the object of the link with other ways):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  eventFire(document.getElementById('myLinkId'), 'click');
});

function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}
```

Source: [How to simulate a click with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript)

With JQuery this is a pretty easy:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myLinkId').click();
});
```

Comment: The clicking works. I just removes the Java Script effect and the Gallery doesnt work at all

Comment: Remove the gallery effect? The gallery effect conflicts with click function?