# Javascript click an input field and enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, click

Is it possible in javascript or Jquery to click on an input field in my case:

```
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="...">
```

and push Enter

Comment: _"and push Enter"_ ? Not certain what Question is ? What is expected result ?

Comment: I think you need focus() and blur() functions for input. Both are jquery function

Comment: I think this is what you are asking for: [How to simulate a click with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript)

Comment: Hm not really, I do want to have this sign '|' (not sure how to explain it better) blinking when I click on the input field

Comment: @JohnDoesLegacy What, exactly, is your desired outcome here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to submit the form when the input is clicked so:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input'),
    form = document.querySelector('form');

input.addEventListener('click', function(){
    form.submit();
});
```

Comment: yes but its not a form to submit its just a textfield to "submit" ( pushing enter key)

Comment: There's no such thing as submitting an input, pushing the enter key submits the form.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of a form you can use JQuery post and get methods Example. $(#id).click(function (){
$.post("url", {variable});
});