# How to click in GreaseMonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am trying to click a button in Greasemonkey.
I have tried two different types of code:

```
var evt = document.createEvent ("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent ("click", true, true);
document.getElementById('BIS_trigger').dispatchEvent (evt);
```

And secondly,

```
var checkoutBtn = document.querySelector (
    "add input"
);
var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
checkoutBtn.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
```

I have had experience with c# and programming before, but am really new with Greasemonkey.

The html:

```
<p>
<input class="btn add-to-cart pull-left" name="add" id="add" value="Add to Cart" type="submit">   
</p>
```

When I enable the little check mark next to the name of my script in my browser then reload, nothing happens. Is it because the thing I am trying to click is an "input"?

If you want to check it out for yourself please go to the site https://www.solefly.com/products/nike-hyperdunk-08-gym-red-white. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to synthesise the event, you can just call the `click()` method on the button. However, your selector is wrong and so you don't actually find the button:

You can do this, finding the button via its `id` property:

```
document.querySelector('#add').click();
```

Note that your selector `add input` searches for a tag with name `add` (which obviously is not there), and then would search for a descendant `input` element under that `add` element. As `id` values are supposed to be unique in an HTML document, you can use a selector on `id`, which requires the `#` prefix.

Comment: Perfect, I'm really grateful for the help :)