# Karma with Webpack and Typescript performs no tests

Tags: typescript, webpack, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Karma testrunner with Webpack and Typescript source files. Taking this source file as the only test file as an example:

**test.spec.ts**

```
var message: string = 'yay';
alert(message);
describe('1st tests', () => {
  it('true is true', () => expect(true).toBe(true));
});
```

And the following karma config:

**karma.config.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-webpack'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter')
    ],

    client: {
      builtPaths: ['app/'], // add more spec base paths as needed
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },

    customLaunchers: {
      // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
      // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },

    files: [
      { pattern: 'app/test.spec.ts', included: true, watched: true },
    ],

    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
      // add webpack as preprocessor
      'app/test.spec.ts': ['webpack']
    },

    webpack: {
      // karma watches the test entry points
      // (you don't need to specify the entry option)
      // webpack watches dependencies

      // webpack configuration
      resolve: {
        //root: [ path.join(__dirname, 'app') ],
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
      },
      module: {
        loaders: [
          // .ts files for TypeScript
          { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'], exclude: '/node_modules/' },
        ]
      }
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

No tests are found when running `karma start`. The browser will start, but it says it finds 0 tests. When I change the `.ts` extension to be `.js` and update the karma config file it does work, so clearly it's the Typescript that messes it up.

However, when running webpack manually with the configuration above, it'll just output a proper javascript file, so the configuration does seem ok...

To be complete, these are the `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` files:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "karma-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "karma": "karma init"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.41",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.18",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "^2.1.5",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
        "useWebpackText": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Karma tests fail in chrome but pass in phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014151/karma-tests-fail-in-chrome-but-pass-in-phantomjs)

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the mime type for Typescript files. Otherwise, Chrome won't run these files.

```
mime: {
  'text/x-typescript': ['ts']
}
```

Comment: Where do we need to add the mime type? (which file)

Comment: karma config file

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this problem. I ended up switching to [karma-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-typescript), which runs the tests flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but for other reasons we need to use Webpack

Comment: We did, but not behind a computer now. I'll try to post our solution later today.

Comment: hey @Robba do you remember what ended up being the problem and how you've fixed it?