# Bundle from karma-webpack Not Loaded

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, karma-webpack

I am trying to set up a hybrid Angular app (AngularJS + Angular) that uses Webpack as its module loader and Karma+Jasmine as the testing framework.  To run the tests, I am using `karma-webpack`; however, **the bundle created by webpack is never loaded in the browser and therefore the tests are never executed** (duh!).  I've tried quite a few things as sanity checks, but I haven't found this problem anywhere else on the interwebs.

So, a little debugging information.  First, my `karma.conf.js` file:

```
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.test');

delete webpackConfig.entry;
delete webpackConfig.output;

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath:           '',
    frameworks:         ['jasmine'],
    port:               8080,
    logLevel:           config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch:          false,
    browsers:           ['Chrome', 'Firefox'],
    singleRun:          true,

    files:              [
      // Some remote libraries that should be loaded.  These all load fine.
      './client/app/app.spec.ts'
    ],

    preprocessors:      {
      './client/app/app.spec.ts': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },

    webpack:            webpackConfig,
    webpackMiddleware:  {
      stats:              {
        colors:             true
      }
    },

    browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,

    client:             {
      captureConsole:     true
    },

    browserConsoleLogOptions: {
      level:                    'log',
      format:                   '%b %T:\n%m\n',
      terminal:                 true
    },

    reporters:          ['mocha'],
    mochaReporter:      {
      output:             'autowatch'
    }
  });
};
```

When running Karma, webpack executes successfully (`karma-webpack` prints `webpack: Compiled successfully.` and I can see the output from webpack); however, the temporary file where the bundle is supposed to be saved (i.e. `/tmp/_karma_webpack_/`) is never created.

I've set `singleRun` option to `false` to see what files are loaded, but the bundle isn't even requested.  However, if I set the log level for Karma to `DEBUG`, I see the following (relevant) output:

```
01 02 2018 12:55:26.678:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/client/app/app.spec.ts?bb6177fad9c0cf145a4962a89c7d2efd0bd0235a /
01 02 2018 12:55:26.678:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /home/c1moore/omninox/omnistack/client/app/app.spec.ts
01 02 2018 12:55:26.678:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/c1moore/omninox/omnistack/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
01 02 2018 12:55:26.678:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/c1moore/omninox/omnistack/client/app/app.spec.ts
```

It *looks* like Karma is trying to serve the file that requires all the tests; however, I don't see that anywhere in the browser.  That is, the file does not appear to be requested/loaded nor do I see any errors that would result from the browser trying to interpret TS as JS.

I didn't include the app.spec.ts file since it seems irrelevant being that it is never actually loaded.  However, it's fairly standard.  It imports all the stuff Angular requires, all vendor libraries, and requires all the tests (using `require.context`).

So, does anybody have any suggestions, pointers, or see something I may have missed?  I've looked over the docs, the code, and various websites trying to find something simple I've missed, hopefully SO has some answers.

Comment: I opened an [issue on Github](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/karma-webpack/issues/298) for anybody interested, but it has received about as much as this post has received.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was frustratingly simple.  I found the answer on some other SO posts ([Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014151/karma-tests-fail-in-chrome-but-pass-in-phantomjs/41054760#41054760) and [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730825/karma-with-webpack-and-typescript-performs-no-tests)).

Basically, Chrome and FF refuses to execute the test files Karma sends them because `karma-webpack` does not change the extension for typescript files from `.ts` to `.js`.  To remedy this, just specify a mime type for `.ts` files in your `karma.conf.js` file like this:

```
module.exports = (config) => {
  config.set({
    // ...

    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript':  ['ts', 'tsx']  // `tsx` is optional depending on your environment
    },

    // ...
};
```