# How to programmatically click on button, THEN do something?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a script where I programmatically click a tab, which reveals more divs on the website, and then perform some actions on those revealed divs.

Right now, I have

`document.getElementById("buttonid").click(); // which reveals another section of the webpage
 console.log($("#idofnewdiv"));`

...but it doesn't seem to see the new div. However, when I manually click on the button, console.log is able to properly print it out. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There's no action on your click and if you are using jQuery, try to maximize the capabilities they gave you. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript

Comment: read more books

Answer (score 0):

```
var button = document.getElementById("buttonid");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
   alert("Button is Clicked");
});

button.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

too you can use it like this:

```
var mButton = document.getElementById("buttonId");

mButton.onClick(function(){

   your code to execute here.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your `click` function is doing anything. The following code assumes that all of the `<div>`s are already hidden.

```
var listOfDivsToReveal = document.getElementsByClassName("divsToReveal");
var listOfDivsIter = 0;
$("#thebuttonID").click(function(){
    if(listOfDivsIter > listOfDivsToReveal.length){
        //do whatever you do when all of your <div> tags are revealed
    }
    listOfDivsToReveal[listOfDivsIter++].style.display = "inline";//Or your desired display.
});
```