# Trigger a click to first element of first element in ng-repeat in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

Hii i need to trigger a click in first elements #first > #second > #third  > .element-for-trigger-click , 
see here

```
<div id="first" ng-repeat="competition in prematchGameViewData track by competition.id">
    <div id="header">...</div>
    <div id="details">...</div>


    <div id="second" ng-repeat="(groupDate, groupGames) in competition.gamesGroupedByDate">     
        <div id="third" ng-repeat="prematchGame in groupGames track by prematchGame.id">
            <div class="element-for-trigger-click"></div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Question : 
How can i get event from Left controller ,find .element-for-trigger-click and trigger a click on right controller with native js . 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aro,

so in following thread you can find information how to 'simulate' click event via native JS on given element (tough by id)

[How to simulate a click with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript)

however I really would not recommend that kind of approach, especially if you use angularJS, as there are ways to do controller to controller communication with angular lib itself like:

- using of angular event bus ($emit, $broadcast and $on)
- using a services
- using pattern of state container like redux (https://github.com/reactjs/redux)
- and probably few more.

Comment: Hi @DonCziken , thanks for answer , Yes im absolutely agree with you  its right way to learn programming ,but its not my project i just do here some edits like this , and  i must do it asap ( im not expert angularjs developer) if  you now better ways please help me

Comment: @Aro well If you just need to do it quick & dirty I think you can just apply the  answer from question I've linked you to.

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch a click event with:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    false, false, false, false, 0, null);

var target = document.getElementById('third').firstChild;
target.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Btw, you wouldn't have to use `.firstChild` if you simply gave that element an ID like all your other elements.

Comment: Hi Joey , for what this part ? true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    false, false, false, false, 0, null ??

Comment: No idea, I stole it from stack overflow