# jQuery .click() function for auto-open popup ad

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, popupwindow

I want that jQuery clicks on any item on the site to open the popup ad from an advertiser. Normally users would have to click on any point on the site, but I want that the Popup opens after loading.

```
    <script src="assets/js/popads.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
      $(function () {
          setTimeout(function () {
              $("#clickme").click();
              ;
          }, 5000);
      });
    </script>
    <li><a id="clickme" href="#intro">Home</a></li>
```

I selected the Home Button for that, but it doesnt't work. The popup opens automatically if a users clicks anything on the page, thats the setting from the ad network not mine. So I don't want to wait until the user clicks, I want that jQuery clicks before the user when the page finished loading, so the popup opens. Any ideas?

Here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/0rdxahj7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an id as the selector with `$("#intro").click();`
If you want to select the link by its href value use:

`$('a[href="#intro"]');`

or alternately assign an id to your link:

`<a id="intro" href="#intro">Home</a>`

Comment: Assigned an ID to it but not working.
<li><a id="clickme" href="#intro">Home</a></li>

Comment: You will need to bind a click function to the link:
`$('#clickme').click(function (e) {

    // do whatever shows your pop-up

});`

Comment: The popup opens automatically if a users clicks anything on the page, thats the setting from the ad network not mine. So I don't want to wait until the user clicks, I want that jQuery clicks before the user when the page finished loading, so the popup opens. Look at the Pastebin I added.

Comment: Without knowing how the ad script is binding the click event it is hard to tell and you will need to figure that part out. Your document ready function will trigger a 'click' event on your home link after 5 seconds.

Comment: It doesn't click even if I change the element it doesn't click on it. I changed it to
    `<a id="clickme" href="#one" class="button style2 down">More</a>`
Here you can watch it: https://unlogis.ch

Comment: I do not think your ad script is binding the click event to the links. You will have to figure out what they are binding the click event to. I cannot help you there. All I can offer at this point is what I have, and that is how to trigger the click event on an element in a timeout function.

Answer (score 0):

You're delaying the click instead of the popup action.

Try this:

```
$(function () {
  $('#clickme').click(function (e) {

    //set the timeOut here
    setTimeout(function () {

      // open the pop-up function like
      $('#pop-up').show(); // or .toggle();

    }, 5000);

  });
}
```

Are you using some particular network for you ads or you built your own?
Because to do what you want, you need a callback function when the ad ends to load.

Because what you're doing is delay the popup, but you should check if popup is loaded.

You could check this library, maybe can help you with loading
- [pace.js](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/).

---

I've modified this [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706236/5500423)

```
function eventFire(){
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent('click', true, false);
    window.dispatchEvent(evObj);
}

window.onload = function() {
  eventFire();
}
```

Comment: I want to delay the click. I thought it would work, but also without delaying the click and just using .click() doesn't work.

The popup opens automatically if a users clicks anything on the page, thats the setting from the ad network not mine. So I don't want to wait until the user clicks, I want that jQuery clicks before the user when the page finished loading, so the popup opens. Look at the Pastebin I added.

Comment: Have you try jQuery `.trigger()`? [Here an example](http://jsfiddle.net/kitsunde/3Zkpm/)

Comment: It's pretty hard to help with that small part of code.