# W3.CSS Navigation Tabs - Select based on URL parameter

Tags: html, css, tabs

I am using W3.CSS Navigation tabs

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

I am now stuck as I want to be able to open the page with a tab pre-selected depending on the URL

So for instance www.example.com/mypage#tokyo would open the page with the Tokyo tab already selected.

Does anybody have an example?

Comment: so you're saying, once you click on a tab and it goes to that page, you want the tab that you clicked on to be selected?

Answer (score 1):

Using window.location.href , you can get the url of the page, then you use .split(/[#]+/).pop() to get the last part of it, and with that you can use the result as a selector to show the correct tab.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the end of your JavaScript:

```
myurl = window.location.href;
londonURL = "www.example.com/mypage#london";
parisURL = "www.example.com/mypage#paris";
tokyoURL = "www.example.com/mypage#tokyo";

function preOpen () {
  if (myurl == londonURL) {
    openCity(event, 'London');
    } else if (myurl == parisURL ) {
      openCity(event, 'Paris');
    } else if (myurl == tokyoURL) {
      openCity(event, 'Tokyo');
    }
};
preOpen();
```

Comment: Within the existing function?

Comment: No behind it, at the end. Make sure you enter the real links (instead of "www.example.com/...") to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

So let's assume this is your Home page.

```html
<a href="pathToFile/test.html#London">London</a>
<a href="pathToFile/test.html#Paris">Paris</a>
<a href="pathToFile/test.html#Tokyo">Tokyo</a>
```

Once you click one of those anchor tags it will bring you to the next page with the tablinks.
In this page (the one with the tablinks) add this JS

```js
function eventFire(el, etype){

  if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}
selectedTab = window.location.href;
console.log(selectedTab);
idUrl = selectedTab.substr(selectedTab.indexOf("#")+1);
console.log(idUrl);
if(idUrl == "Tokyo"){
 eventFire(document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")[2], 'click'); 
}
if(idUrl == "Paris"){
 eventFire(document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")[1], 'click'); 
}
if(idUrl == "London"){
 eventFire(document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")[0], 'click'); 
}
```

This will simulate a click on the desired tablink from the previous page based on the id.

This line: `selectedTab = window.location.href;` gets the url.
This line: `idUrl = selectedTab.substr(selectedTab.indexOf("#")+1);` Finds the index of the # on the url and adds one to it so you can get the id you're looking for.

Here: `if(idUrl == "Tokyo"){
    eventFire(document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")[2], 'click'); 
}` Here we set a condition if thats the desired ID then we pass as the first parameter the class name of that tablink in this case is position 2 on the array of classnames tablinks.
The event functions is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript)

See the screenshots as an example. Hope this helps.

Home:[image]

London clicked based on the url passed.[image]

**Edit 2**
Use this see comments for explanation

```js
selectedTab = window.location.href;
idUrl = selectedTab.substr(selectedTab.indexOf("#")+1);
// Get the Classes
arr = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
// Loop through the array and a condition to find if the id on the url is similar to the one in the
// array, if so then call the function and pass that parameter.
for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
 if(idUrl == arr[i].innerText){
  eventFire(arr[i],'click');
 }
}
```

Remove this:

```js
selectedTab = window.location.href;
console.log(selectedTab);
idUrl = selectedTab.substr(selectedTab.indexOf("#")+1);
console.log(idUrl);
if(idUrl == "Tokyo"){
 eventFire(document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")[2], 'click'); 
}
if(idUrl == "Paris"){
 eventFire(document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")[1], 'click'); 
}
if(idUrl == "London"){
 eventFire(document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")[0], 'click'); 
}
```