# How I can push that button in browser console?

Tags: javascript, html

I have button declarated:

```
<input type="submit" 
value="Rejestruj" 
class="submit semitransparent" 
onclick="return IsAnyGroupChecked();">
```

How I can push that button in browser console? :)
Please help me...

Comment: I want to push that button in browser console. I found: document.getElementById("button1").click(), but I don't know how to use it with my button :(

Comment: Eliran don't working :(

Comment: It only says in console true and nothing happend

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate a click with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript)

Comment: If duplicate so what is the solution?

Comment: If duplicate then please go visit the other question and accepted answers.

Comment: I go visit, but I don't know how I should do that

Comment: Have you noticed that you didn't set the id of the button? You shoud put id="button1" at your input tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('foo').click();
```

This does the trick.

Give it id instead of class and you will be able to do it.

If you can't give it an ID and need to use the class this will do:

```
var foo = document.getElementsByClassName('foo'); 
foo[0].click();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got: TypeError: document.getElementByClass is not a function

Comment: What? How I can do it on site? :D

Comment: Do you understand me?

Comment: Yes so this is not your own website I suppose give me a min

Comment: Yeah It is not my website and I want to push that button in console (:

Comment: I think you can use my answer now ;)
This works at least when I try it in a simplified version

Comment: Okay, but what I should write instead of "foo" ?

Comment: Because I have only button declarated: <input type="submit" 
value="Rejestruj" 
class="submit semitransparent" 
onclick="return IsAnyGroupChecked();">

Comment: submit semitransparent

Comment: You should first enter in console>>>


var foo = document.getElementsByClassName('submit semitransparent')

Comment: Then enter the second line>>> foo[0].click();

Comment: Yeah I did that <3