# How can I make a <i> element clickable without listening to a keypress?

Tags: html, angular

I have a few `<i>` elements with glyphicons and I want them to be triggered when I press the ENTER key. I am using Angular 2
 How can I do this?

```
<i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-menu-down down"
                   *ngIf="!(sort.name === 'Last Name' && sort.order > 0)" (click)="sortTrips('name')" ></i> .
```

Comment: Try attaching `click` event.

Comment: <i class="" onclick="javascriptFunction()"></i>

Comment: Sorry my question is incomplete. I want the click event to be accessible with keyboard when hitting the ENTER key. I've already read couple of articles but the only solution i found was to listen to keypress.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate a click with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript)

Comment: When one say "click", it usually means click with a mouse and / or touchscreen. But apparently you want the element to be selectable with tab and react to keyboard event, right ?

Comment: Yes I want the element to be triggered when I press ENTER on keyboard

Comment: Your question title _is the opposite_ of what you want.  You _do want to listen_ to keypress.  How else do you intend for this to respond to the `ENTER` key?

Comment: I wanted to find a UI solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer (only for Angular 2):

```
<div (keyup.enter)="function()">
 <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-menu-down down"><i>
</div>
```

In this situation the application is working as inttended.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an event like @HassanIman say it looks like :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This example demonstrates how to assign an "onclick" event to a p element.</p>

<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me.</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You try see the full exemple in this website : [W3SCHOOLS ONCLICK EVENT](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick_html)

Comment: https://alligator.io/angular/binding-keyup-keydown-events/ . Here you can find additional details