# Chrome bookmarklet to expand all the page links

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, bookmarklet

How can I create a Chrome bookmarklet to expand *more examples* links so I don't have to click each link separately:
http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/take
The bookmarklet should open all *more examples* links on a single click.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a bookmarklet or how to select and click on each *more examples* button

Comment: @chbchb55: How to make a bookmarklet to expand all the page links on a single click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `.querySelectorAll` and `.click`

To click on all of these buttons, first, you need to know how to select them.

Upon inspection, the `class` of the buttons' parents are `vi_more`. So, to target the `a` directly inside them we can do `document.querySelectorAll('.vi_more>a')`. [For more on `document.querySelectorAll`, visit the MDN Web Docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

After obtaining the `NodeList` filled instances of `HTMLAnchorElement`, we can iterate over them with `.forEach` and click each one of them with `link.click()`. [For more on `HTMLElement.click`, visit the MDN Web Docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

Here is what your bookmarklet could look like:

```js
javascript:document.querySelectorAll('.vi_more>a').forEach(link => link.click())
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to create a Chrome extension.

You would want to create a background script to capture the click on your chrome extension icon and then send a window message to your content script, which would be added to the page code. Then you can get the page elements you need, in this case the links and simulate a click on them.

You can get started with Chrome Extensions [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted).

[Simulating a click with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript)

Comment: "I assume you want to create a Chrome extension." Thanks for the answer, but as I said I need a Chrome [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet).

Comment: Fair enough, sorry for the misunderstanding.