# How to have the Bootstrap's collapsible navbar open by default?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a **`Bootstrap`** navbar with the toggle button. How do I get this navbar to be open by default when it is on collapsed mode or on page load? I've tried setting `data-toggle="collapse"` attribute to `data-toggle="collapse.show"` and now it shows by default but requires two clicks to close. How can I get it open by default and work as expected?

The navbar code is like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    /* content */
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using ?

Answer (score 7):

If you want the navbar to be open by default when it is on the collapsed mode, then you have to add the **`show`** class to the item that holds the collapsible menu (the one holding the **`collapse`** class), like this:

```
<div class="collapse show navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    /* content */
</div>
```

Reference: [Bootstrap Collapse Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#example)

Here you have an example, so you can see it working...

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    BRAND
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse show navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
     <ul class="navbar-nav">
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: A fantastic answer. Thank you :)

Comment: This answer, with `.collapse.show`, i.e. `class="navbar-collapse collapse show"`, is for Bootstrap 4. If you’re still using Bootstrap 3, use `.collapse.in`, i.e. `class="navbar-collapse collapse in"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#navbar").click();
});
```

```html
<button id="navbar" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: i am using this in a React project and am not using jQuery in it.

Comment: do you have any VanillaJS suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript