# JQuery Event Button Simulate Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, onclick

I want to trigger the Street Icon on in [this browser game](http://cityinc.se/#/). In other games it was easy by using the document.getElementById.

In Firefox the button shows up as jQuery. However if I create an event function nothing happens.

This is what I did, copied the event from inspector into a function and called streetIcon(); in the console.

```
function streetIcon() {
    function (d) {
        var e = function() {
          g(b, {
            $event: d
          })
        };
        Gg[a] && c.$$phase ? b.$evalAsync(e) : b.$apply(e)
      }
}
```

However, it doesn't work like with document.getElementById.

Is there a way to trigger buttons div class or so? I feel like I'm doing this wrong so pointing to the correct documentation is much appreciated.

Comment: So that's a function (e) declared inside an anonymous function, which is declared inside a third function (streetIcon)... I'm not sure there's even a way to trigger this. `streetIcon` doesn't even _return_ the function that's inside (so one could do `streetIcon()()`). But without returning it... scratching my head

Comment: Most examples I found looked different to the event I found. If it's not possible without reverse engineering the game, a hint for an alternative way would be nice. Something that I can run in the console rather than something like pyautogui. edit - I see now this is what others meant with hidden element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simulate a click with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript)