# jQuery - manually trigger link inside of a <div> that gets clicked on

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I simulate an anchor click via jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery)

For some reason I thought this would be really easy.  Here's my code:

```
$('#someDamnedDiv').live('click', function () {
    $('a', this).trigger('click');
});
```

What the Sam Hill is wrong with my function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to simulate a click on a link. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery). However, you could do this:

```
$('#someDamnedDiv').live('click', function (event) {
    window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: seems like one of the answers to that question actually does show a cross-browser way to do this!  See the answer referencing Selenium...

Comment: @Ryley well that looks promising! but I'm not gonna test it in every browser right now :)

Comment: There's another question about this subject [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421584/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-to-an-anchor-tag)

Comment: This one does the trick.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

this is what i use for one of my projects:

```
$('div.classname').click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('a')) return;
    $(this).find('a').click();
});
```

Comment: Just what I was needing so that hrefs inside of clickable divs are still active. Thanks!