# How to simulate a click on a element which also results in invoking attached events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, dom-events

My test case is @ Gmail, I am trying to simulate a click to open the first e-mail with JavaScript.

Actually I did a successful attempt which is done by firing a mousedown event.

But I wonder if there is a generic method to generate "organic" clicks instead of me wasting time on investigating attached events ?

Comment: What's wrong with `$("#elementID").click()`?

Comment: @Frédéric - This presumes that all event handlers are attached to a `click` event, when there's other events such as `mousedown` and `mouseup` that a user-click would trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just trigger the usual suspects...but other than that, there's no good generic way to simulate a native click from a user (and an *actual* native click is impossible, for example making an `<a>` go to it `href`, without doing the redirect yourself).

Triggering the relevant events to a `click` for something like gmail would look like this:

```
$(selector).mousedown().mouseup().click();
```

Comment: I don't agree with you about events can't make an anchor follow its href, because I did it with document.createEvent. However chaining seems the solution so far. Meh, it is time to hack webkit lol.

Comment: @Ozgur - No kidding, I'd love to see an example of this that works cross-browser.  Unless something changed (AFAIK), IE still requires `createEventObject` instead, and even then you're not doing the *native* behavior, for example: Ctrl+Click opens in a new window, etc.  That's why I emphasized *actual*, usually you're kind-of or partially simulating a native event, but not all the way there.

Comment: You are right there is no cross-browser native click, but Firefox is the only outsider. Every other browser supports simulating a native `click` event and following `href`'s, obeying `target` attribute, etc. For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421584/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-to-an-anchor-tag/1421968#1421968

Comment: @Crescent - That still doesn't seem to work for ctrl+click, shift+click, etc, doing whatever the user has setup for each (or defaults)...that's my point, it's not native, it's "kind of" native, missing pieces.