# Jquery /javascript Based on hashtag in url find a tag that points to the same url and do something

Tags: jquery, hash, hyperlink, tags, find

I have a kind of complicated question here.

Right now I am running a script on my page that, when a user clicks on a link, I use jQuery's `.load()` to load an image from a custom attribute called 'imglocation'.

This all works fine; my question is the link the user clicks puts a hash tag in the url which i want to then use to match with a link on the page and run the same function as if the user clicked on it. The idea being that when you send someone a link when they open it in their browser the function will run and show the image that someone has sent to them.

What I was trying to do is:

```
var hashedLink = location.hash;
var findLink = $(".photothumb a").attr("href");

if(hashedLink == findLink){

// In here set some variable to flag the link
// then load the image based on the attr imgLocation of the same link.

}
```

If this is possible please let me know.

Comment: It's possible, can you post some sample html to show what page structure, and elements, you're working with?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like the following ...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   var findLink = $(".photothumb a[href='" + location.hash + "']");

   if (findLink.length > 0) // we found the link with the hash in the href
   {
      findLink.click(); // click the found link
   }
}
```

I have not tested this, and you may want to play with the selector a tiny bit to make sure the hash tag exists in the href, but this should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Most of what you are asking for should be trivial, except for the part where you 'emulate' a click on the link.

Links by default, do not have a click event; there are a myriad of ways to get a similar behavior, and you should use any of those variations, e.g. just call the function that the click event would have called, if a true click is not needed.

But if you really want to emulate a click on a link, you should read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421584/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-to-an-anchor-tag).  Note that the only reason you would ever need to emulate a click is when you have a bunch of event handlers attached to that link, and you have no way of determining what those events are.