# How to automate a click on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to click on the specified xy position on a page without an actual click. I have tried many jquery and js scripts, but they did not work for me. Is this something possible with jQuery?

Edit: Not for any affiliate fraud ad clicks or something evil.

Comment: I apologise if I'm wrong, but most of the reasons I can think of for wanting to do this are not good reasons.

Comment: @ahadley: Yeah, I smell kind of cheating

Comment: `@Ajmal:` In a comment on andreapier's answer, you've said *"I want my users to click on a link when they entered into that page. Its just only an ad.. "* FWIW, in all advertising systems I'm familiar with, that's fraud. Obviously I don't know what specific system you're using, but it's hard to imagine one where it's not. Separately, it's also very, very much not what I would want as a user. If I caught a site doing it, I would never go back to that site again.

Comment: Your comments below show your use to be entirely inappropriate.

Comment: Rename to "How to do click fraud" maybe? ;)

Comment: Are there any StackExchange about fraud this could be migrated to perhaps?

Comment: Seriously: What's the policy about questions on how to do fraud and other criminal activity? Is this a close reason?

Comment: Why don't you just use a popup like every other annoying advertisement out there?

Answer (score 3):

Just put a div into your document with id `click` and trigger click with

```
$("#click").click();
```

I feel that clicking on specific cords is even impossible task

Example

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="click"><a href="/advert/profit/1">advert here</a></div>
<script> $("#click").click(); </script>
```

Comment: Not working. Could you please explain this with an example? Also I need to click on a specific postion on screen.

Comment: @Ajmal: added practical example

Comment: That will only fire handlers attached via jQuery, not handlers attached in any other way (DOM0, DOM2, IE's DOM2-like `attachEvent`, ...).

Comment: @Ajmal: we won't do everything for you. You have to include jQuery framework

Comment: @Ajmal: So you'll be probably banned from the adservice, it'S 1000% against their TOS

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Didn't even know this. So I have to use trigger()?

Comment: @Ajmal: Sure it will not work on adsense and Advert services which are good

Comment: @genesis: Actually, I think it might fire DOM0, at least on some browsers, but not DOM2: http://jsbin.com/ayedus I don't know that you can reliably simulate a DOM2 mouse click cross-browser. (I know you *shouldn't*.)

Comment: @Ajmal: Who cares? It's still you faking an action to make money. Sounds like click fraud to me, even with an affiliate program. Certainly would be with Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if you bind the function you want to run to the load event itself... Emulating a mouse click generally is not a best programming practise.
Can you provide some code about what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want my users to click on a link when they entered into that page. Its just only an ad..

Comment: Except this is a quite unfair operation, if you cannot specify your code we cannot help you.  
Keep attention to what you are doing: i'm pretty sure this is not admitted by you ad provider.

Comment: If it's your own affiliate link you don't need to click it automatically... However @genesis answer should do the trick.  
Trust me, you'll get lots of problems doing what you want. Users will not trust you and will not come back to your site. DO NOT DO SUCH A THING.

Comment: @Ajmal: Perhaps you should ask your ad provider if they have an API you can use to execute click fraud with them? ;P

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete test case that simulates the `click` event, calls all handlers attached (however they have been attached), maintains the `"target"` attribute (`"srcElement"` in IE), bubbles like a normal event would, and emulates IE's recursion-prevention. Tested in FF 2, Chrome 2.0, Opera 9.10 and of course IE (6):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script>
function fakeClick(event, anchorObj) {
  if (anchorObj.click) {
    anchorObj.click()
  } else if(document.createEvent) {
    if(event.target !== anchorObj) {
      var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); 
      evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null); 
      var allowDefault = anchorObj.dispatchEvent(evt);
      // you can check allowDefault for false to see if
      // any handler called evt.preventDefault().
      // Firefox will *not* redirect to anchorObj.href
      // for you. However every other browser will.
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div onclick="alert('Container clicked')">
  <a id="link" href="#" onclick="alert((event.target || event.srcElement).innerHTML)">Normal link</a>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="fakeClick(event, document.getElementById('link'))">
  Fake Click on Normal Link
</button>

<br /><br />

<div onclick="alert('Container clicked')">
    <div onclick="fakeClick(event, this.getElementsByTagName('a')[0])"><a id="link2" href="#" onclick="alert('foo')">Embedded Link</a></div>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="fakeClick(event, document.getElementById('link2'))">Fake Click on Embedded Link</button>

</body>
</html>
```

[Demo here.](http://jsbin.com/iyadi)

It avoids recursion in non-IE browsers by inspecting the event object that is initiating the simulated click, by inspecting the `target` attribute of the event (which [remains unchanged during propagation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling)).

Obviously IE does this internally holding a reference to its [global `event` object](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling). DOM level 2 defines no such global variable, so for that reason the simulator must pass in its local copy of `event`.

### Conclusion - call javascript method as below in pageLoad or as you wish.

```
fakeClick(event, document.getElementById('link'))
```

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421584/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-to-an-anchor-tag/1421968#1421968)