# How to use target in location.href

Tags: javascript, window.open

I am currently developing a web application where I need to open a popup window to show a report. The problem is that some versions of explorer don't support the window.open javascript function, so when this is the case I catch the error and open the new url with location.href. Here the code:

```
try {
    window.open(url, "","width=1002,height=700,location=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,status=1,resizable=0")
} catch(e) {
    location.target = "_blank";
    location.href = url;
}
```

The problem is that the location.target is not working and I would like to know if there is a way to specify the target of the location.href so it can be opened in a new tab.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The problem is that some versions of explorer don't support the window.open javascript function

Say what? Can you provide a reference for that statement? With respect, I think you must be mistaken. [This works](http://jsbin.com/unevus) on IE6 and IE9, for instance.

Most modern browsers won't let your code use `window.open` except in direct response to a user event, in order to keep spam pop-ups and such at bay; perhaps that's what you're thinking of. As long as you only use `window.open` when responding to a user event, you should be fine using `window.open` — with all versions of IE.

There is no way to use `location` to open a new window. Just `window.open` or, of course, the user clicking a link with `target="_blank"`.

Answer (score 27):

try this one, which simulates a click on an anchor.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href='http://www.google.com';
a.target = '_blank';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I posted this answer after I tried it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XLLEk/ and it's working on my machine. You propably have prevented all popup windows in your browser, that's why it doesn't work in your case. If so, please consider remove the downvote, thanks.

Comment: qiao: You don't know who downvoted your answer. You know I commented, and you know someone downvoted. That's all you know; making assumptions based on that is a bad idea. Regarding the answer: Using default settings on Chrome, IE9, and Firefox, all three block the pop-up. Appropriately. So it doesn't offer anything on top of `window.open`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Really sorry for the assumption.

Comment: qiao: No problem, when I was new to SO I made similar assumptions. Sometimes the assumption is right (it was in this case), sometimes -- frequently -- it's wrong. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, it was really kind of you to teach me this lesson :)

Comment: Works for me in Chrome (and FF for that matter).

Comment: I think it could easily lead to a downvote if you post an answer that assumes that the user does not block popups or that it is ok that the solution only works on one machine.

Answer (score 15):

You can use this on any element where onclick works:

`onclick="window.open('some.htm','_blank');"`

Comment: The question is not how to set a handler, but how to programmatically set the `target` of a link. Your post does not answer that question.

Comment: This particular post was quite useful to me in a pinch +1.

Comment: Thanks man! this solution not only works, but is easy to incorporate within one line of 'code'.

Comment: I used this answer to open link in an iFrame with a button. Very useful.

Answer (score 4):

If you go with the solution by @qiao, perhaps you would want to remove the appended child since the tab remains open and subsequent clicks would add more elements to the DOM.

```
// Code by @qiao
var a = document.createElement('a')
a.href = 'http://www.google.com'
a.target = '_blank'
document.body.appendChild(a)
a.click()
// Added code
document.body.removeChild(a)
```

Maybe someone could post a comment to his post, because I cannot.

Comment: Works like a charm! (with semicolons after each command, obviously)

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
         function newWindow(url){
                window.open(url);
            }
        </script>
```

And call the function

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an `<a/>` to trigger the report, you can try this approach.  Instead of attempting to spawn a new window when `window.open()` fails, make the default scenario to open a new window via `target` (and prevent it if `window.open()` succeeds).

HTML

```
<a href="http://my/url" target="_blank" id="myLink">Link</a>
```

JS

```
var spawn = function (e) {
    try {
        window.open(this.href, "","width=1002,height=700,location=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,status=1,resizable=0")
        e.preventDefault(); // Or: return false;
    } catch(e) {
    // Allow the default event handler to take place
    }
}

document.getElementById("myLink").onclick = spawn;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a hidden anchor tag on the page with the target set as you need, then simulate clicking it when you need the pop out?

[How can I simulate a click to an anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421584/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-to-an-anchor-tag)

This would work in the cases where the window.open did not work

Comment: Not today, but I have used this technique in the past

Comment: I have to say I'm not buying it. Would you do a demo? Of this working, in modern browsers, without a user event?

Comment: this probably wont work without user interaction..just tested it on a setTimeout..no go, pop up blocker caught it on chrome

Comment: Again: *Without* a user event. Your example happens in response to a click; you may as well us `window.open`. (I tried to do an updated fiddle, but http://jsfiddle.net is so slow I gave up. Your fiddle came up right away, but then jsfiddle disappeared for me so I can't even copy your code to http://jsbin.com -- much more reliable in my experience -- to test whether it works without the user event.)

Comment: Ah, you commented while I was typing (and waiting for jsfiddle).

Answer (score 0):

As of 2014, you can trigger the click on a `<a/>` tag. However, for security reasons, you have to do it in a `click` event handler, or the browser will tag it as a popup (some other events may allow you to safely trigger the opening).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLLEk/8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="url" target="_blank"> <input type="button" value="fake button" /> </a>
```