# Javascript not working in Chrome?? but in FF and IE works

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to create a button using a div. This div button will call a linkbutton onlick event. for some reason its not working in chrome. Its not firing the button event in Chrome? But it works fine in other browsers..

Here is my code..

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1"
    ValidateRequest="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="dvButton" runat="server" ></div>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="DummyBtn" runat="server" Text="Dummy" OnClick="DummyBtn_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnConfigId" runat="server" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnSelected" runat="server" />

    </form>
</body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function Selected(value, selected) {

        document.getElementById('<%=hdnConfigId.ClientID %>').value = value;

        document.getElementById('<%=hdnSelected.ClientID %>').value = selected;

        document.getElementById('<%=DummyBtn.ClientID %>').click(); //This does not work in Chrome

    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           dvButton.InnerHtml = "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" id=1234 onclick=\"javascript:Selected('1234','Test');return false;\" >TEST</a>";
        }

        protected void DummyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string id = hdnConfigId.Value;
           string selected = hdnSelected.Value;
           //Logic to retrieve data by passing these parameters into DB

        }      
    }
}
```

RENDERED SOURCE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head><title>



</title></head>

<body>

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="WebForm1.aspx" id="form1">

<div>

<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />

<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUHNjcxMjAzMQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ8WAh4JaW5uZXJodG1sBWo8YSBocmVmPSJqYXZhc2NyaXB0OnZvaWQoMCk7IiBpZD0xMjM0IG9uY2xpY2s9ImphdmFzY3JpcHQ6U2VsZWN0ZWQoJzEyMzQnLCdUZXN0Jyk7cmV0dXJuIGZhbHNlOyIgPlRFU1Q8L2E+ZGSqT177YHIKIjfz5j0oOl9lGktifA==" />

</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

var theForm = document.forms['form1'];

if (!theForm) {

    theForm = document.form1;

}

function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {

    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {

        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;

        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;

        theForm.submit();

    }

}

//]]>

</script>





<div>



    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBALUn5j+AQKEzpmBDwKf7rOjAgLVqJ/GB0fyISUyIuzPcZ4CYvSLltNpE/oA" />

</div>

    <div id="dvButton"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id=1234 onclick="javascript:Selected('1234','Test');return false;" >TEST</a></div>

       <a id="DummyBtn" href="javascript:__doPostBack('DummyBtn','')">Dummy</a>





    <input name="hdnConfigId" type="hidden" id="hdnConfigId" value="1234" />

    <input name="hdnSelected" type="hidden" id="hdnSelected" value="Test" />

    </form>

</body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function Selected(value, selected) {



        document.getElementById('hdnConfigId').value = value;



        document.getElementById('hdnSelected').value = selected;





        document.getElementById('DummyBtn').click();



    }

    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: I see a space after each .ClientID, try removing the space and let us know if that fixed or not your issue

Comment: Can we see the rendered source?

Comment: @Dorin That won't fix his issue. The space is server-side, so will not cause a space client-side.

Comment: @RB. so C# will automatically remove the space?

Comment: Daniel, it would really help you to not mix code and content here, especially try to lose the classic-asp style embedded values like <%=hdnConfigId.ClientID %>. The code would be clearer, and would not require a recompile on every visit!

Comment: Do you see an error in Chrome's JavaScript Console?

Comment: Its just not working on Chrome?? Very Weird???

Comment: @Dorin There's no space to remove. It's equivalent to this code: `MyTextbox.Text = "Hello World"   ;`. There is no space in the string...

Comment: Yes it shows an error on console.. as Uncaught TypeError: Object javascript:__doPostBack('DummyBtn','') has no method 'click'
Selected
(anonymous function)
onclick

Comment: @RB. I was refering to "<%=hdnSelected.ClientID[SPACE]%>", but it seems that the spaces gets removed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check :
[How can I simulate a click to an anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421584/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-to-an-anchor-tag)

The problem is that DOMElement.click() method is not supported by every browsers, and firefox just implemented it recently for exemple.

The link I provided provides an alternative, or you could use jQuery ;)

Comment: oo why didn't I think of that?

Comment: FIXED IT CHANGED THE LINKBUTTON TO BUTTON. :-) The button is going to be hidden so does not matter. Thanks for all the help and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call an anchor tag's click event from javascript directly, at least in some browsers.

There is an example of how to do it here:  [How can I simulate a click to an anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421584/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-to-an-anchor-tag)

Also, you could use jQuery, as I'm pretty sure that handles all the nasty stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to use .click() you have to use jQuery and  include it, what you did not do !
jQuery Startup Tutorial:
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: He isn't using jQuery. This is plain JS.

Comment: Yes he did, but there isn't any in the code. Therefore including the jQuery library will not fix his problem.

Comment: Actually what EvilP says is right. If he used jQuery, this would work.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry, posted before I saw the source.

First and foremost, isn't `value` and `selected` reserved words? That may present problems in older versions of IE.

You are triggering a click event on an anchor that has no onclick handler.

Comment: No still not fixed the issue in Chrome browser?? Keep getting Uncaught TypeError: Object javascript:__doPostBack('DummyBtn','') has no method 'click' in the Chrome console..

Comment: The problem is you are triggering a `click()` in your Selected() function on an anchor that has no onclick event.

Comment: I don't think you can even trigger `click()`'s on anchors. Only on form fields.