# Difference between .click() and actually clicking a button? (javascript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

I'm trying to figure out this weird issue I've been having, and the root cause is the **difference between a live click and triggering `.click()`**.

I won't get into the details of the problem, but basically when you click on the input button it works fine (has an `onclick` event). But if I call `.click()` from somewhere else (instead of physically clicking the button) it doesn't work properly.

My question is - is there a way to truly replicate an actual click on a button?

---

***EDIT***

The problem: I'm opening a new window (aspx page) that loads an inline PDF. **If I actually click on the link, the window opens fine and the PDF loads. If I use `.click()` the window opens and I'm prompted to download the PDF file.** I've been through Adobe Reader settings, browser settings, and registry settings about the prompting - I understand that these can be factors to the big picture, but right now I'm concerned about why the behavior between a mouse click and .click() are doing anything different at all.

Comment: "_I won't get into the details of the problem_"... but that's what we do here. Sounds like something else isn't working, because `.click()` should trigger a click.

Comment: Could be that the button is submitting a form when clicked (I don't remember whether this works with `click` or not), or maybe that it handles `mouseup` and/or `mousedown` events instead of `click`.

Comment: @Shannon: If my answer was helpful to you, please accept it as the correct answer so this question can be marked as resolved. If you still have issues with it, I would love to assist. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use this function to truly mimic a mouse click:

```
function clickLink(link) {
    var cancelled = false;

    if (document.createEvent) {
        var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            false, false, false, false,
            0, null);
        cancelled = !link.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    else if (link.fireEvent) {
        cancelled = !link.fireEvent("onclick");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Before reading the below, which discusses how to circumvent the problem, let me answer more fully why you're having the problem to begin with:

Modern browsers take different actions for links based on things like which mouse button you clicked with, whether you held <kbd>Shift</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and so on. As an example, in Chrome, if you middle-click a link instead of left-clicking, the browser will automatically open the window in a new tab.

When you use `.click()`, jQuery has to make assumptions about the "way" in which you clicked - and you get defaulted behavior - which in your case, is not the correct behavior. You need to specify the "correct" settings to the browser in the form of `MouseEvents` settings in order to fix the issue.

Now, on to a short discussion of ways to fix it:

When you are using jQuery's `.click()` event with no parameters, this is not actually "faking a click" on the element in question. Instead, according to the jQuery documentation at http://api.jquery.com/click/ :

> ... when `.click()` is called without arguments, it is a shortcut for .trigger("click")

This means that when you fire `$('#div1').click()` - if there is no actual jQuery handler for the `'click'` event, you will get default processing. So, consider these two cases:

**Case 1**:

```
<a id='myLink' href='/some/link/'>Click me!</a>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#myLink').click();
</script>
```

In this first scenario, the `.click()` call does nothing, because there is no handler for it. The event triggers, but there is nothing to catch it and respond - so the `a` tag's default handling is used, and the user is taken to `/some/link/` - and since you haven't specified which mouse button or any other parameters - it's truly default.

**Case 2**:

```
<a id='myLink' href='/some/link/'>Click me!</a>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#myLink').bind('click', function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();

        alert('you clicked me!');
    }).click();
</script>
```

In this scenario, because a `click` handler was created, when the user clicks the link - the `ev.preventDefault()` and `ev.stopPropagation()` calls will stop the default handling from occuring, and the alert will be fired.

At this point, however, you have an `ev` object which represents the `MouseEvents` - and you could change the settings if you desired. For instance, you could do the following:

```
ev.altKey = true; // Held Alt
ev.button = 1;    // Middle Mouse Button
```

These settings will change the default method of handling the event.

**Alternative, non-jQuery solution**

You can also truly simulate a button-click by adapting the following code.

```
function fakeClick(event, anchorObj) {
  if (anchorObj.click) {
    anchorObj.click()
  } else if(document.createEvent) {
    if(event.target !== anchorObj) {
      var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); 
      evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 
          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null); 
      var allowDefault = anchorObj.dispatchEvent(evt);
      // you can check allowDefault for false to see if
      // any handler called evt.preventDefault().
      // Firefox will *not* redirect to anchorObj.href
      // for you. However every other browser will.
    }
  }
}
```

(For a more full implementation, see the original post at: [How can I simulate a click to an anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421584/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-to-an-anchor-tag/1421968#1421968) - and look at the selected answer)

This will actually fake the browser into believing that you mouse-clicked the anchor / span / etc by building the event from scratch in the same way that the browser's default handlers do - except that you can override some of the settings. I don't suggest this approach, however, as it's a lot more prone to breaking on cross-browser application and you have to figure out what all of the parameters map to.

Answer (score 7):

```
  $('img').click(function(event){
    console.log(event.hasOwnProperty('originalEvent')); // output : true

  });
  $('img').trigger("click",function(event){
    console.log(event.hasOwnProperty('originalEvent')); // output : false

 });
```

Comment: please add some description to explain what and how your code will fix it.

Comment: @Dvir Azulay code is perfectly mimicing  the mouse-click , i just gave example to check whether click is my mouse-click or by trigger.

Comment: Maybe not what the OP wanted, but this helped me differentiate between an actual click and a trigger click event, just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, this helped me capture a user click, as opposed to a script click.

Answer (score 3):

To create and trigger a click event same as user-click :

```
function simulateClick() {
  var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });
  var cb = document.getElementById('checkbox');  //whichever element you want to click
  var cancelled = !cb.dispatchEvent(event);
  if (cancelled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault.
    alert("cancelled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
    alert("not cancelled");
  }
}
```

of course, call the function like this.

```
simulateClick();
```

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

note : initMouseEvent() is deprecated. Avoid using it, instead use MouseEvent() as shown in this solution.