# Pass mouse event to function by using js click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one `onclick` as below

```
<div class="tablinks active" onclick="openmarket(event,this)" data-uid="1">
```

`openmarket` function like below

```
function openmarket(evt, obj) {
    var i, tabcontent2, tablinks2;
    tabcontent2 = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent2");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent2.length; i++) {
        tabcontent2[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks2 = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks2");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks2.length; i++) {
        tablinks2[i].className = tablinks2[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(obj.getAttribute('data-uid')).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Here in this function I have passed 2 parameters,
 1) event 
2) object

now I try to click this div by JS like below.

```
$("div [data-uid='1']").click();
```

but it won't work because I guess parameter `evt` is not valid or mismatch from what it should be.

Can anyone help me ?

Thank you.

**Edit**
I'm getting following error.

> Cannot read property 'className' of undefined

and error line is `evt.currentTarget.className += " active";`

Comment: may I know the reason for voting `close` ?

Comment: why don't you add a callback to the click and pass event and this to the openmarket function

Comment: @SabirAmeen, can you please explain how ?

Comment: @SabirAmeen, clicking on div itself calling openmarket function, so, if I create a callback, it will be called again. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console? Does it work when you actually click on the element instead of simulating a click programmatically?

Comment: @MikaelLennholm, yes, If I click on div it works, but if I click using click() function, it won't

Comment: try to use `evt.target.className`.

Comment: This is expected behaviour as your not actually clicking the div but instead using jQuery click function to simulate the click. Both are different. This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127908/difference-between-click-and-actually-clicking-a-button-javascript-jquery  and yes `evt.target.className` will work in both cases

Comment: post all html not only a small part , this 'll be useless !

Comment: @bRIMOs, my HTML is about 2400 lines of code, do I need to post here ?

Comment: create a js fiddle or a plunker will be sufficient

Answer (score -1):

Your selector query is wrong

change `$("div [data-uid='1']").click();`

to `$("div[data-uid='1']").click();`

this will return a jqueryclick click event not a mouse click event

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple javascript :

It works well. I fthere is only one div, use and id instead of a class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<!--I wish to append it here-->
<body>

    <div  class="tablinks active uid1" onclick="openmarket(event,this)" 
   data-uid="1" style="height:30px;width:50px;background-color:red;">
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function openmarket(evt, obj) {
    var i, tabcontent2, tablinks2;
    tabcontent2 = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent2");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent2.length; i++) {
        tabcontent2[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks2 = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks2");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks2.length; i++) {
        tablinks2[i].className = tablinks2[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(obj.getAttribute('data-uid')).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
var list=document.getElementsByClassName("uid1");
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    list[i].click();
}
</script>
```