# jQuery .click() does not work in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have seen several similar posts with solutions that seemed to have worked for those people, but I CANNOT get this to work.

I am using http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/ in my project. It works PERFECTLY, in all browsers, except in Safari the "BROWSE" button does not open a file dialog. The following code exists in script.js (which is included for the plugin to work):

```
$('#drop a').click(function(){
    // Simulate a click on the file input button
    // to show the file browser dialog
    $(this).parent().find('input').click();
});
```

The .click() does not fire in Safari. I have tried the solution as per [jQuery .click() works on every browser but Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925153/jquery-click-works-on-every-browser-but-safari) and implemented

```
 $('#drop a').click(function(){
    var a = $(this).parent().find('input');
    var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evObj.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window);
    a.dispatchEvent(evObj);
});
```

But then I get the error that `dispatchEvent is not a function`. I then did some research on this, and tried the jQuery.noConflict() route, but this did not resolve the error. Also, I use a LOT of jQuery in my main file and I cannot have the noConflict() mode activated for the entire page. There is also no reason that the jQuery should be conflicting with anything as I am only using jQuery and normal javascript and I am not using anything like prototype or angular. Does anybody know of another way to simulate a click in Safari?

**UPDATE:** Just FYI, I have added an `alert('test')` in the mentioned function (which triggers when "BROWSE" is clicked), and I do get the alert in Safari, but it is not simulating the click of the file input element, i.e: it is not openening the file dialog.

Comment: try this $(this).parent().find('input').trigger("click");

Comment: try `var a = $(this).parent().find('input')[0];`

Comment: @sudharsan: On a jQuery object, `.trigger("click")` and `.click()` are the same thing.

Comment: @jalynn2, I no longer get the `dispatchEvent is not a function` error in Firefox and it works, but it is still doing nothing in Safari. Not sure where to go from here in terms of debuggin in Safari...

@T.J. Crowder, I have submitted a comment to your answer.

Comment: Just FYI, I have added an `alert('test')` in the mentioned function (which triggers when "BROWSE" is clicked), and I do get the alert in Safari, but it is not simulating the click of the file input element, i.e: it is not openening the file dialog.

Comment: I finally figured out that the click() call would work if I called it closer to the user click event or tap on the screen. If I first sent a packet to the server for validation and then called click() when it returned, then it wouldn't work. I have to change my logic or flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second section of code in my original question turned out to work, except for 2 things.

1) The method does not like jQuery, so instead of

`var a = $(this).parent().find('input')[0];`

I assigned an ID to my file input and instead called

`var a = document.getElementById('upload_select');`

2) Safari blatantly ignores this if the input is hidden (`display:none;`), which is was, so instead I made the input font-size = 1px; and opacity = 0.

Implementing these two changes got the code working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12925565/157247) more closely. :-)

`dispatchEvent` is a function on the DOM element, not the jQuery object. You're trying to call it on the jQuery object. So:

```
$('#drop a').click(function(){
    var a = $(this).parent().find('input')[0];
    // Change here -----------------------^^^
    var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evObj.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window);
    a.dispatchEvent(evObj);
});
```

Using the `[0]` on the jQuery object gives you the first DOM object in the jQuery object, or `undefined` if the jQuery object is empty.

Comment: Ok, I thought that was because the jQuery was retrieving an array and they wanted to reference the first element that was retrieved. I am now no longer getting the `dispatchEvent is not a function` error in Firefox (and it works), but it is still not working in Safari. It just does nothing. I don't normally use Safari, so I am unsure where to go from here in terms of debugging for Safari...

Comment: @Magnanimity: It may just not be possible with the current Safari. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/210709/157247) from tvanfossen suggests your original thing worked for him in Safari, and he usually knows what he's doing. If that doesn't do it, there's an [interesting workaround here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3030174/157247). It's a workaround rather than "solution" but quite a good one.