# .click event is not working in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a `.click` event in JavaScript, it seems to be working fine in all major browsers except for safari. Code is creating a dialog box that display's an image when the submit button is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(new function () {
var SpinnerImage = ('<div id="dialog-message"><img src="loading.gif" /></div > ');
$("#ctl00_mainContent_AppPaymentControl1_applicationPaymentControl_payNow").click(function () {
    //show loading gif
    $('body').append(SpinnerImage);
    $("#dialog-message").dialog(
        {
            title: 'Loading... Please Wait'
        });
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if it will make a difference, but take the `new` off of your function on the first line.  It's not necessary

Comment: `new function () {` <-- not sure where you learned that. You may want to bind on mousedown. Might be a timing issue with the form submitting?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497825/jquery-click-does-not-work-in-safari

Comment: @epascarello its not a timing issue cause it works in all other browsers.

Comment: @SyedVasty Why do you want to trigger the button click even on page load?

Comment: @Win i dont, i was trying to see if that would fix the problem. It's working on all of the browsers except for safari. I think it's the .click that not working.

Comment: If you `alert()` within the `click()` event does the alert show? Also just a tip, you can use `$('[id$=idOfControl]')` to grab controls on pages with master pages so that you dont have to deal with the id mangling. So in this scenario, assuming `payNow` is your control id, you can just use `$('[id$=payNow]')`.

Comment: @JoshMein I'll give alert() a try. thanks

Answer (score 0):

See if this works?

```
1  $(document).ready(function () {
2     var SpinnerImage = $("<div id='dialog-message'><img src='loading.gif' /></div>");
3     $("#ctl00_mainContent_AppPaymentControl1_applicationPaymentControl_payNow").click(function () {
4        //show loading gif
5        $('body').append(SpinnerImage);
6        $("#dialog-message").dialog(
7           {
8              title: 'Loading... Please Wait'
9           }
10       );
11    });
12 });
```

Corrections:

- Remove `new` on line 1
- Add `$` on line 2
- Fix faulty single- and double- quotes on line 2

---

You mentioned in a comment that `#ctl00_mainContent_AppPaymentControl1_applicationPaymentControl_payNow` is an `<input>` element. Try using the `$(element).focus(callback);` method instead of `$(element).click(callback);`

Comment: No. It did not work. I read somewhere that safari does not support .click? anyone know if this is true?

Comment: @SyedVasty Desktop or mobile Safari? What's the version?

Comment: @SyedVasty What is the element tag of `#ctl00_mainContent_AppPaymentControl1_applicationPaymentControl_payNow`?

Comment: @SyedVasty No, that's the attribute. I'm asking for the element. You know, like `div`, `span`, `input`, etc?

Comment: @SyedVasty Instead of `.click(`, try `.focus(`