# jQuery.on click doesn't work in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, onclick

I'm currently facing a problem where my **on click** function **doesnt trigger in safari** but does work in other browsers.

I have **two span elements** which should work **as buttons**

**HTML:**

```
  <span class="firstLink" onclick=""><a>addClick + </a></span>
  <span class="secondLink" onclick=""><a>removeClick -</a></span>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('body').on('click', 'span.firstLink', function() {
    currentClick++;
    clickPerformer(currentClick);
});

$('body').on('click', 'span.secondLink', function() {
    currentClick--;
    clickPerformer(currentClick);
});
```

Here's **clickPerformer** function:

```
function clickPerformer(i) {
    var obj = {
        show: function() {
            alert(i);
        }
    };
    obj.show();
}
```

Previous code is all inside

```
$( function() {
    // here
});
```

When I call clickPerformer when page loads, it works. But not when I click on those two 'buttons'.

When I put

> alert('blah blah...')

inside

> $().on('click')

it wont work aswell.

Any ideas what might cause the problem?
All help appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925153/jquery-click-works-on-every-browser-but-safari

Comment: This is not a good way of forming your HTML using `<a class="firstLink">addClick + </a>` would be much better with `event.preventDefault();` in the click function. You will also need to add `event` to the function params like so `$('body').on('click', 'span.secondLink', function(event) {...}`