# How to get link inside div and click it using js

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to write a function for an extension that can find a link inside a specific div and click it. The link has no id or class name, so I was looking for something similar to a CSS selector but with JS without using '$' or 'jQuery' since that will require me to embed a jquery library with the extension.

The div has a class name and then a link inside, so this is the code I have so far --

```
function COut() {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('bottom_row').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var elem = a[i],
    elem.click();
  }
}
```

This the markup for the div and link -

```
<div class="bottom_row">
                <a onclick="miniAddToCart.closeMiniAddToCart({cmConversionEvent: 'Checkout'})" href="http://www.domain.com/shoppingcart/default.cfm?checkout=1&amp;"><img src="http://www.domain.com/images/eb/minicart/checkout.gif" alt="Checkout"></a>
            </div>
```

Any ideas what Im doing wrong?

Comment: can you share the dom.

Comment: If you do not want to use jQuery, why would you tag it jQuery?

Comment: @epascarello I want to use jquery but I have to avoid using things like $() or jquery() in my code mark up cause it will cause issues unless i download and package the jquery library with the extension, which isnt ideal.

Comment: Are you trying to trigger an onclick event or make the link actually navigate away?

Comment: Im trying to actually click the link and navigate to the url in the href

Comment: Hmm why would you be going through all of the links then?

Comment: @thealfreds I dont want to go through all of the links, only the one link in that specific div. Its the only link in that div and I dont have a way of adding a id or class to the <a> tag, so I have to use the div class name to target the link.

Comment: Since I know this is for a Chrome Extension and from my experience on the various similar questions popping up lately, I want to point out that in many pages as the one you target the interaction with a form is less straightforward than you might think. E.g. you may think you just need to set the value of an input field and click a link, but in order for this to work you might need to set the values of some hidden fields, change some elements' classes, setting special `data-*` attributes etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
getElementsByClassName('bottom_row').getElementsByTagName('a');
```

getElementsByClassName returns a set, not a single item

```
getElementsByClassName('bottom_row')[0].getElementsByTagName('a');   
                                    ^^^
```

If there can be more than one item with the className, than you will need to loop. And if you support modern day browsers, you can look into [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

And finally clicking on a link is not as easy as calling click()

[How can I simulate a click to an anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421584/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-to-an-anchor-tag)

If you want it to do to the url, you might be better off just setting window.location.href

Answer (score 0):

If there is a single A tag, I won't prefer to make loop for that. Instead you can just do it like:

```
function COut() {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('bottom_row')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
  if(a){
    a.click();
  }
}
```