# do events manually in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to execute DOM events manually? For example, if you have a link and want to call the default event function of it through code:

```
<a href="one.html" id="a">main page<\a>
```

```
document.getElementById("a").onclick();
```

Comment: You can't. Grab the href and use `window.location` to follow the URL.

Comment: Err, you can. see the marked duplicate.

Comment: @Hamish http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421584/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-to-an-anchor-tag. A hyperlink is _not_ an event.

Comment: Right, an even better dupe. vote to close with that instead :)

Comment: Window.location didnt work for javascript codes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out **[initMouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initMouseEvent)**

> Intializes the value of a mouse event once it's been created (normally using document.createEvent method.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/ZnfKq/)

```
var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"),
    anchor = document.querySelector('a');

event.initMouseEvent("click", true, 
                     true, window, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, false,
                     false, false, false,0, null);

anchor.dispatchEvent(event);
```

[Example provided by MDN as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk%3aDOM/event.initMouseEvent)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this following Way

```
document.getElementById("a").onclick=function(){f1()};
function f1()
       {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=3;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use trigger events like below

```
var triggerEvent = function (element, name, data) {
var event;
if (window.CustomEvent) {
    event = new CustomEvent(name, {
        detail: data || {},
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
    });
} else {
    event = document.createEvent("Event");
    event.initEvent(name, true, true);
    event.detail = data;
}
element.dispatchEvent(event);
 };
```

You will use it like

```
 triggerEvent(input, 'change', {changedText : "Custom data here in this Object"}
```

You may get below error based on configuration

```
Refused to display 'https://www.some.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=50JbU_yHKdGQiAec9IH4Bg' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery will do what you want here quite nicely:

http://api.jquery.com/click/

```
$("#a").click();
```

This will automatically call the href and the dom event attached to the matched element.

Comment: Downvoted because if the user wanted a jQuery solution they would've asked or tagged it so.

Comment: I disagree. The question was "is it possible to execute DOM events manually" and I linked to a solution that accomplishes that "through code". I would have downvoted the answer for lack of an example, not the jquery solution

Comment: The convention here on SO is that you don't provide answers using jQuery (or any other library) if that library is not mentioned specifically in the question.

Comment: Feel free to suggest jQuery in the comments, but "use jQuery" answers dilute the value of SO for vanilla javascript questions.