# How can I execute EventListener 'click' from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, webkit, addeventlistener

I have event listener `myObject.addEventListener('click',this.doSomething,false)` on  element. 
It works fine when I do mouse click but I cannot figure out how to trigger click from JavaScript. It seems like `element.click()` does not work for divs?

I am using jQuery and I have also tried `trigger('click')` but nothing is happening.

How can I in JavaScript execute the EventListener?

Update:

Here is sample code http://jsbin.com/iniwi5/2

Comment: There are tons of exact duplicates, e.g. [how can I trigger a JavaScript event click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click), [JavaScript: Invoking click-event of an anchor tag from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980709/javascript-invoking-click-event-of-an-anchor-tag-from-javascript), etc.

Comment: Neither of those "duplicates" are formulated with event listeners in mind.

Comment: Yes, this is specific for Event Listener, if I was using normal jQuery .click() listener the code works just fine but seems like addEventListener behaves differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you bind the event using jQuery instead?

```
$(myobject).click(function() {

});
```

Then

```
myobject.trigger('click');
```

would programmatically trigger the click.

Comment: 'click'ing a div is basically a custom event which you can't do natively.  So I agree - this is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: I agree this as workaround, I could not figure out to make this with Event Listeners so I refactor my code to use .click()

Answer (score 0):

To trigger a click event listener added via `addEventListener`, you need to manually dispatch a click event, using either [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) (for standards-compliant browsers) or [`fireEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (for IE < 9).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
myObject.click; // no `()`
```

OR:

```
(myObject.click)();
```

Comment: `myObject.click` is wrong -- if click exists at all, it's a function. The second example is the same as `myObject.click()`, which is only standardized for [INPUT elements of certain types](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-2651361). You can't rely on arbitrary elements to support it.