# How to use an anchor tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a slider script that can link to other tabs in the slider using anchor tags

The html

```
<a class="st_ext" href="#tab_<? echo $next_tab; ?>"
     rel="st_horizontal<? echo $audit_id; ?>">tab link</a>
```

This will move to the slider to the next tab.  It works if I wrap it around the submit button but then the ajax query doesn't work).

Question is, how would I put this into a jquery success response?  I would like it f the user can click on the button that triggers the ajax call and if it is successful it opens the next tab on the slider using the above method.

The jQuery ajax

```
type: "POST",
url: "ajax/image_audit.php",
dataType: "json",
data: $('#audit_form'+form_id).serialize()+'&standard_used='+standard_in_sight,
    success: function(response){
         ------> call to anchor tag here
}
```

Alertnatively, if I can't do this is there a way that I can add the tag to the button so that the jquery is called first before the tag?

The button..

```
    <input type="button" 
 name="audit_submit" class="audit_submit audit_submit_btn ie7_submit" value="" />
```

The ajax is called using the `audit_submit` class as the trigger

Comment: Programatically calling an anchor tag doesn't call the default action, it will call the javascript handler for the element.

Comment: I have don't have access to the handler, it was a plugin I bought and the supposed support for the plugin don't respond to emails

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980709/javascript-invoking-click-event-of-an-anchor-tag-from-javascript

Comment: @RameshK - I'm looking but I'm struggling with working out how to use it in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  `$(".st_ext").click();` if you have many elements styled with `st_ext` add id to the anchor element and call something like below

```
<a id="click_me" class="st_ext" href="#tab_<? echo $next_tab; ?>"
     rel="st_horizontal<? echo $audit_id; ?>">tab link</a>

$("#click_me").click();
```

hope it helps.