# Prevent default event and resume afterwards

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-events

I want to create an angularjs directive for restricted actions of my web site. For example I have  an anchor which would trigger a route change in angular, but before that I want to show a modal login dialog.

I can stop the routing with `preventDefault`, but I can't resume the routing. I have also tried with dummy event triggering (`element.triggerHandler('click')`) without success.

I'd like to apply the directive not only to route changing but any other action.

```
.directive('loginRequired', ['AuthService', 'AUTH_EVENTS',
function(AuthService, AUTH_EVENTS) {
    return {
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', function(e) {
                if (!AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#myModal').modal();
                    scope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess, function() {
                        //resume event
                    });
                    console.log('$scope.$on happened');
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is:

```
.value('lastPrevented', {
    elem : null
}).directive('loginRequired', ['AuthService', 'lastPrevented',
function(AuthService, lastPrevented) {
    return {
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', function(e) {
                if (!AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
                    lastPrevented.elem = element;
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#myModalLogin').modal();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]).run(['lastPrevented', '$rootScope', 'AUTH_EVENTS', '$timeout',
function(lastPrevented, $rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, $timeout) {
    $rootScope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess, function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            if (!!lastPrevented.elem) {
                lastPrevented.elem[0].click();
                lastPrevented.elem = null;
            }
        })
    });
}]);
```

That's not resuming... which literally I think is not feasible.
The solution is inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980709/javascript-invoking-click-event-of-an-anchor-tag-from-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Event.preventDefault()` will capture or delay events. AFAIK, it only cancels them outright (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)). I don't believe there's a way of resuming the original event with its handler(s) in tact. (But perhaps you don't intend the term 'resume' to be taken quite so literally.)

In this specific case, I think you'll have to examine `$(e.target).attr('href')`, and later** use it to update the route (you'll need to inject the `$location` service ([Docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/docs/api/ng/service/$location)) and use its `.path()` getter/setter method).

-- Best of luck!

---

**Quick note: you're most likely going to want to pass your 'resume' handlers to your  `AuthService.isAuthenticated()` method, as a callback, as it may wait on some kind of asynchronous business. Rough example:

```
element.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  newRoute = $(e.target).attr('href');
  AuthService.isAuthenticated(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal();
    scope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess, function() {
      $location.path(getWhatYouNeedFromUrlString(newRoute));
    });
  }));
});
```

You'd setup your `.isAuthenticated()` method to fire the callback when the user is indeed authenticated.